# When you use a particular country settings do not work addresses onion

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, relays

When you use a particular country settings do not work addresses onion:

```
# This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved
# The old torrc file was renamed to torrc.orig.1 or similar, and Tor will ignore it

DataDirectory C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor
GeoIPFile C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip6
HiddenServiceStatistics 0

#-------------------------------------------------
StrictNodes 1
EntryNodes {US}
ExitNodes {US}

#{ac},{af},{ax},{al},{dz},{ad},{ao},{ai},{aq},{ag},{ar},{am},{aw},{au},{at},{az},{bs},{bh},{bd},{bb},{by},{be},{bz},{bj},{bm},{bt},{bo},{ba},{bw},{bv},{br},{io},{vg},{bn},{bg},{bf},{bi},{kh},{cm},{ca},{cv},{ky},{cf},{td},{cl},{cn},{cx},{cc},{co},{km},{cg},{cd},{ck},{cr},{ci},{hr},{cu},{cy},{cz},{dk},{dj},{dm},{do},{tp},{ec},{eg},{sv},{gq},{ee},{et},{fk},{fo},{fj},{fi},{fr},{fx},{gf},{pf},{tf},{ga},{gm},{ge},{de},{gh},{gi},{gr},{gl},{gd},{gp},{gu},{gt},{gn},{gw},{gy},{ht},{hm},{hn},{hk},{hu},{is},{in},{id},{ir},{iq},{ie},{im},{il},{it},{jm},{jp},{jo},{kz},{ke},{ki},{kp},{kr},{kw},{kg},{la},{lv},{lb},{ls},{lr},{ly},{li},{lt},{lu},{mo},{mk},{mg},{mw},{my},{mv},{ml},{mt},{mh},{mq},{mr},{mu},{yt},{mx},{fm},{md},{mc},{mn},{me},{ms},{ma},{mz},{mm},{na},{nr},{np},{an},{nl},{nc},{nz},{ni},{ne},{ng},{nu},{nf},{mp},{no},{om},{pk},{pw},{ps},{pa},{pg},{py},{pe},{ph},{pn},{pl},{pt},{pr},{qa},{re},{ro},{ru},{rw},{ws},{sm},{st},{sa},{uk},{sn},{rs},{sc},{sl},{sg},{sk},{si},{sb},{so},{as},{za},{gs},{su},{es},{lk},{sh},{kn},{lc},{pm},{vc},{sd},{sr},{sj},{sz},{se},{ch},{sy},{tw},{tj},{tz},{th},{tg},{tk},{to},{tt},{tn},{tr},{tm},{tc},{tv},{ug},{ua},{ae},{gb},{uk},{us},{um},{uy},{uz},{vu},{va},{ve},{vn},{vi},{wf},{eh},{ye},{zm},{zw}
ExcludeNodes {ac},{af},{ax},{al},{dz},{ad},{ao},{ai},{aq},{ag},{ar},{am},{aw},{au},{at},{az},{bs},{bh},{bd},{bb},{by},{be},{bz},{bj},{bm},{bt},{bo},{ba},{bw},{bv},{br},{io},{vg},{bn},{bg},{bf},{bi},{kh},{cm},{ca},{cv},{ky},{cf},{td},{cl},{cn},{cx},{cc},{co},{km},{cg},{cd},{ck},{cr},{ci},{hr},{cu},{cy},{cz},{dk},{dj},{dm},{do},{tp},{ec},{eg},{sv},{gq},{ee},{et},{fk},{fo},{fj},{fi},{fr},{fx},{gf},{pf},{tf},{ga},{gm},{ge},{de},{gh},{gi},{gr},{gl},{gd},{gp},{gu},{gt},{gn},{gw},{gy},{ht},{hm},{hn},{hk},{hu},{is},{in},{id},{ir},{iq},{ie},{im},{il},{it},{jm},{jp},{jo},{kz},{ke},{ki},{kp},{kr},{kw},{kg},{la},{lv},{lb},{ls},{lr},{ly},{li},{lt},{lu},{mo},{mk},{mg},{mw},{my},{mv},{ml},{mt},{mh},{mq},{mr},{mu},{yt},{mx},{fm},{md},{mc},{mn},{me},{ms},{ma},{mz},{mm},{na},{nr},{np},{an},{nl},{nc},{nz},{ni},{ne},{ng},{nu},{nf},{mp},{no},{om},{pk},{pw},{ps},{pa},{pg},{py},{pe},{ph},{pn},{pl},{pt},{pr},{qa},{re},{ro},{ru},{rw},{ws},{sm},{st},{sa},{uk},{sn},{rs},{sc},{sl},{sg},{sk},{si},{sb},{so},{as},{za},{gs},{su},{es},{lk},{sh},{kn},{lc},{pm},{vc},{sd},{sr},{sj},{sz},{se},{ch},{sy},{tw},{tj},{tz},{th},{tg},{tk},{to},{tt},{tn},{tr},{tm},{tc},{tv},{ug},{ua},{ae},{gb},{uk},{um},{uy},{uz},{vu},{va},{ve},{vn},{vi},{wf},{eh},{ye},{zm},{zw}
#-------------------------------------------------
```

normal addresses works, for example: www.whoer.net
https://s4.postimg.org/ucw4h8ny5/image.png

Onion addresses but does not work...

Comment: This is expected behaviour. You've specified StrictNodes which means that Tor will fail circuits rather than use nodes in your exclude list. It's possible that some connections will require use of nodes outside of the US. To be sure that this is the issue in this instance, please also include your Tor logs.

Answer (score 1):

You have jailed yourself to use US-only nodes for **all the circuits** - so it's normal. Drop the `ExcludeNodes` line and you will be just fine! If you will make an *outside query*, i.e. for an clearnet website - EntryNodes + ExitNodes are just fine for you and you will preserve your geolocation tweak, but in case of onions/HiddenServices you actually don't care at all: a rendezvouz points are cut off by your ExcludeNodes clause and you simply can't reach the onion hidden service - that's how your fail happens.

Comment: ENTRY NODE > MIDDLE NODE > EXIT NODE
http://pastebin.com/raw/b0e6fCkL

1. Still I do not understand why the use of one country only work normal web addresses and "onion" do not work

2. Using (MIDDLE NODE) country other than entry and exit node does not Tor Browser will not start
http://pastebin.com/raw/5h064WV9

When setting NODE (CZ > CZ > CZ) it is possible to make "normal" and  "onion" websites to function somehow?

Comment: please attach your full torrc so I'll take a look

Comment: EXAMPLE:
US > DE > US = http://pastebin.com/raw/ZWk237aw

EXAMPLE:
CZ > CZ > CZ = http://pastebin.com/raw/r5WQMM7f

Comment: comment ExcludeNodes and try

Comment: `[WARN] You have asked to exclude certain relays from all positions in your circuits. Expect hidden services and other Tor features to be broken in unpredictable ways.`